# Option for package minted to color math mode commands

Tags: minted

I am using the `minted` package to display LaTeX commands in my LaTeX courses.

I noticed, that minted uses two different colors, depending on text or math mode.

Compare the output of this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{minted}
 
\begin{document}
\mintinline{latex}{$\sin \alpha$} vs. \mintinline{latex}{\sin \alpha}.

It would be nice, if output of \mintinline[mode=math]{latex}{\sin \alpha} 
would be in blue color,  as in \mintinline{latex}{$\sin \alpha$}.
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image: different colors used by minted based on text or math mode]

Is there any way, to provide an option or something similar to the `minted`-commands, that ensure, that `minted` uses the math mode colors but without showing the `$` in the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of cheat by utilizing the different styles that are available for `minted`.
For example, setting `[style=borland]` provides you with a nice blue colour on what is technically a text example, but for your display purposes coloured in blue as math:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{minted}
 
\begin{document}

\mintinline{latex}{$\sin \alpha$}  

\mintinline{latex}{\sin \alpha}

\mintinline[style=borland]{latex}{\sin \alpha} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kind of an idea :-) Unless I feel, I want to change the color scheme.  But thank you very much for this suggestion.  Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @Jan Well, then you'd just have to pick two "reverse" schemes. :p